# Getting Null pointer Exception while running cucumber test with selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

**This is Class with cucumber annotations**

```
public class EndtoEndTest {

WebDriver driver;
//private ConfigFileReader cnffilered;
//private CartPage cartpage;
//private Checkoutpage checkoutpage;
//private ProductListingPage productlistingpage;


@Given("^User is on Homepage$")
public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws Throwable {


    ConfigFileReader cnffilered= new ConfigFileReader();
    cnffilered.getBrowserType();
    cnffilered.getUrl();
    cnffilered.Implicitwait();
    cnffilered.MaxmimizeWindow();

}

@When("^he searches for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void he_searches_for(String arg1) throws Throwable 
{

        HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver);
        homepage.perform_Search(arg1);

}
}
```

**This is the class with FageFactory Initialization**

```
public class HomePage {

 WebDriver driver;

public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//a[@class='noo-search icon_search']")
private WebElement click_on_search_icon;

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using="//input[@class='form-control']")
private WebElement enter_data_for_search;

public void perform_Search(String search) {

    click_on_search_icon.click();
    enter_data_for_search.sendKeys(search);
    enter_data_for_search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

}

public void navigateTo_HomePage() {

    driver.get("http://www.shop.demoqa.com");
}

}
```

Driver Initialization

```
package dataProviders;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ConfigFileReader {

private static Properties properties;
private final String propertyFilePath = "F:\\Cucumber_Framework\\Cucumber_Framework\\src\\main\\resources\\configs\\Configurations.properties";
private WebDriver driver;
private ConfigFileReader cnffilered;


public ConfigFileReader() throws IOException
{

        properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(propertyFilePath);
        properties.load(fis);
        //fis.close();

}

public  void Implicitwait()
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} 

public  void MaxmimizeWindow()
{
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
public  String getUrl() throws IOException
{


    String url = properties.getProperty("url");

    if(url!=null)
    {

        driver.get(url);


    }

    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("URL is not specified in configuration.properties file");
    }

    return url;


}

public  String driverpath() throws IOException
{

    //cnffilered = new ConfigFileReader();

    String driverpath = properties.getProperty("driverpath");

    if(driverpath!=null)
    {

        //driver.get(driverpath);
        return driverpath;

    }

    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Driver path is not specified in configuration.properties"); 
    }

}

public  String getBrowserType() throws IOException
{
     cnffilered = new ConfigFileReader();

    String Browser_Type= properties.getProperty("BrowserType");

    if(Browser_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",cnffilered.driverpath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    else if(Browser_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    else if(Browser_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer") || Browser_Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",cnffilered.driverpath());
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Browser type is not specified in configuration.properties"); 
    }

    return Browser_Type;

    }
    }
```

**While executing i am getting Null Pointer Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.click(Unknown Source)
at pageObjects.HomePage.perform_Search(HomePage.java:27)
at stepDefinations.EndtoEndTest.he_searches_for(EndtoEndTest.java:42)
at ✽.When he searches for "dress"(src/test/resources/functionalTest/EndtoEndTest.feature:9)
```

I have understand one thing that may be driver instance is getting null, but what may be the solution for that, Any help?? thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is definitely your lack of initialization of the web driver.  How you initialize it depends entirely on which webdriver you want to use.

Comment: Bill Hileman, Thanks for reply any solutions for that??

Comment: Can you update the question with the feature file?

Comment: @Ab123 Where is the driver initialization code?

Comment: @Grasshopper Please find the driver initialization code

Comment: i have updated my code for driver initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver that has been initialized in the ConfigFileReader class needs to be passed to the stepdefinition class to initialize the driver variable of that class.

Add the last line to the stepdefinition given method.

```
@Given("^User is on Homepage$")
public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws Throwable {

    ConfigFileReader cnffilered= new ConfigFileReader();
    cnffilered.getBrowserType();
    cnffilered.getUrl();
    cnffilered.Implicitwait();
    cnffilered.MaxmimizeWindow();
    **this.driver = cnffilered.getDriver();**
}
```

Add method `getDriver()` in class `ConfigFileReader`

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

If they are in the same package make the driver variable in `ConfigFileReader` protected and access it directly without need for a driver variable in the stepdefinition class.

Comment: Thanks, @Grasshopper it is working now , what is think here as soon as   cnffilered.MaxmimizeWindow(); is executed driver initliazation is getting destroyed and that's why it was throwing null pointer exception. am i correct??

Comment: Great catch and nice explanation !!!

Comment: @Ab123 Nope that is not correct. It has got nothing to do with selenium. It is all about access of variables in Java code. Refer to this -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html